Sufficient conditions on Fourier coefficients that imply smoothness
Given a square-integrable function $f$, let $\hat{f}(n)$ denote its Fourier coefficients. It is well-known that differentiability of $f$ implies that the $\hat{f}(n)$ satisfy certain bounds, i.e. they decay rapidly. I am interested in a clean implication going in the other direction: Is there a bound on the $\hat{f}(n)$ that guarantees $f$ must be smooth of some order?
For example, to keep things concrete, what is a sufficient condition on $\hat{f}(n)$ that guarantees $f$ is Lipschitz continuous? Analogous assertions for higher-order smoothness (e.g. Hölder, Sobolev, etc.) are welcome as well.
I found this related question, but the accepted answer is not precise. I am looking for a precise implication.

The result is basically the same as the one for Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$. For a distribution $f$ on $\mathbb{T}$, $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $f \in H^s(\mathbb{T}) \iff \langle j \rangle^s \hat{f} \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, where $\langle j \rangle = (1 + |j|^2)^{1/2}$.

There is a theorem of Bochner from which I think can be deduced that for $f$ to be $k$ times differentiable and for $f^{(k)}$ to be a linear combination of continuous positive definite functions, it is necessary and sufficient that $(n^k\hat f(n))_{n\in\mathbf Z}\in\ell^1(\mathbf Z)$.

Some precise results are: $\mathcal{F} : C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}) \to s(\mathbb{Z}) = \{a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}: \sup_{j}\langle j \rangle^Na(j) < \infty \text{ for all }N\}$ is a bijection. Also $\mathcal{F} : H^s(\mathbb{T}) \to \{a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}:\langle j \rangle^s a \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\}$ is a bijection. Refer to chapter 3 of "Partial Differential Equations I" by M. Taylor.
Another result called Bochner's theorem is that $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ is positive definite if and only if $\hat{f}$ is a finite positive measure on $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\hat{f}(j) \geq 0$ for all $j$ and $\|\hat{f}\|_{\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})} < \infty$.
